# Increasing memory size in R on Linux

Tags: r, linux, memory

I am using Linux through a Virtual Machine (I need to in order to run this R code which uses Linux specific commands). I am using R version 3.3.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu on my Virtual Machine. I want to allocate larger memory size for R, since my code fails to finish due to memory size issues. I know in R on Windows you can use memory.limit(size=specify_size) to increase the size of the memory allocated, how would I do so on Linux in a straight forward fashion.

Comment: I am likely wrong here, but my understanding is that R will use everything it can in a Linux environment. Can you allocate more memory when establishing the virtual environment?

Comment: Linux does not limit an application's memory allowance like Windows does. Most likely your code requires more memory than the VM has available.

Comment: Yes I should be able to allocate more memory to the virtual box itself and I will try that. I had allocated about 50 GB to the VM, and R produced an error that said something along the lines of "Cannot allocated vector of size 3.3 MB" which has caused me some confusion.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by increasing the Base Memory of the Virtual Machine as well as increasing the CPU from 1 to 4. The code is running well now. I thank all for their suggestions.

Comment: @OrysyaStus I have the similar problem running R in linux machine. How can I increase CPU from 1 to 4 in linux ?

Comment: @OrysyaStus Can you please tell what do you mean by increasing CPU from 1 to 4?

Answer (score 0):

Compiled from comments:

R will use everything it can in a Linux environment, which does not limit an application's memory allowance like Windows does. As code requires more memory than the VM has available, more memory should be allocated when establishing the virtual environment.

The problem was solved by increasing the Base Memory of the Virtual Machine as well as increasing the CPU from 1 to 4. The code is running well now.